# Any sort of "Hidden" attribute in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, attributes

I'm trying to write a dynamic control in Microsoft MVC that lets me edit the entity in a grid (specifically using jqgrid).  Well, I build my columns and colmodels in my controller based on the entity I'm trying to modify.  I'd like to have a way to mark a column as a hidden column, but I'd like to not just create arbitrary Attributes if a standard one already exists.  So I'm looking through System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations which has a lot of good things in it, but not what I'm looking for.  Does such an attribute exist?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [DisplayAttribute.AutoGenerateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.autogeneratefield.aspx)?  You could set that to **false** when you want to not autogen UI for that property.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this and couldn't use the suggested solution because I don't have .NET 4 available for this project.

So ended up using the `EditorBrowsableAttribute`, which also controls e. g. the visibility of properties in the Visual Studio Designer and IntelliSense:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a045wyx(v=VS.80).aspx

It's available since .NET 1.0.

Comment: I personally prefer `BrowsableAttribute` in `System.ComponentModel` namespace. I would even go as far as to say they are logically interchangeable. The difference is `EditorBrowsableAttribute` has three states (the third state is referred to as `Advanced`) whereas `BrowsableAttribute` only has two: "Hidden" and "not hidden".

Comment: I'm using a DevExpress PropertyGrid in WPF and BrowsableAttribute(false) is ideal for hiding in that situation of not defining PropertyDefinitions in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You also might check out

https://web.archive.org/web/20200923094147/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/06/14/a-closer-look-at-the-hiddeninput-attribute-in-mvc-2.aspx

Note that it's in the System.Web.Mvc namespace--

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.hiddeninputattribute.aspx